# MySql: Order by Path (string)

Tags: mysql, adjacency-list

I need to order categories by path, following the [adjacency pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmqmt.jpg):

```
SELECT e.id_category 'id',
    p.tPath
FROM (category c)
LEFT JOIN `category_path` p ON c.id_category = p.id_category
ORDER BY p.tPath, c.id_category ASC
```

The paths of categories are saved as TEXT column, the problem is when I need to sort IDs that have more of one digit:

[image]

16 has 1 as first digit, then is the first row within the **/1/2/** category

It is possible to have this?:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing numbers, it would be better to zero pad the numbers to a fixed length.  But, that may not be feasible for multiple reasons.  So, one method is to extract the components, convert each component to a number, and sort on those:

```
order by (case when path like '/%'
               then substring_index(substring_index(path, '/', 2), -1) + 0
               else -1
          end),
         (case when path like '/%/%'
               then substring_index(substring_index(path, '/', 3), -1) + 0
               else -1
          end),
         (case when path like '/%/%/%'
               then substring_index(substring_index(path, '/', 4), -1) + 0
               else -1
          end)
```

You can continue this for as many parts as might be in the string.

Comment: What happen if are infinite levels?

Comment: @csotelo . . . Then you would have a *very* long query ;)  This works up to a certain number of levels, which you have to specify in the query.  Alternatively, zero-pad the values when you create the paths, so they are sortable.